# Adding to the PATH environment variable / editing the .bashrc file

Tags: linux, environment-variables, path, bashrc

I'm very much a newbie with Linux (coding in general really) but I've have taken the plunge and installed Mint for my coding projects.

I've installed Julia, which I use to run numerical simulations but for haven't been able to run it by typing `julia` in bash. I am able to run it by specifying the full path `\home\mark\julia-1.5.1\bin`. The Julia website suggests editing either the `~/.bashrc` file or `~/.bash_profile` to add to the path variable with `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/<Julia directory>/bin"`.

I've tried this with no success. In fact, after the change I can't run basic commands in bash. I just get a command not recognised error.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong! Probably something stupid. If anyone could shed some light on my issues, I would be most grateful. It would be fantastic you could give an explanation of the issue / fix in the most basic of terms. Hopefully this could serve as a PSA to help other new users!

Many thanks.

Edit: results of `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Please run `echo $PATH` and add the output to the question.

Comment: It doesn't fit. (1) `\home\mark\julia-1.5.1\bin` does not look like a full path to `julia` in Linux. Do you mean `/home/mark/julia-1.5.1/bin/julia`? (2) The output from `echo $PATH` looks quite sane, it should allow you to run standard commands, there is *no sign* of `/path/to/<Julia directory>/bin`. // What *exact* line did you add? To what file?